# Does AD B2C offer in-app authentication instead of jumping to b2clogin.com

Tags: active-directory, authentication

my customer is using AD B2C to authenticate their users to their web sites and mobile apps. However, the requirement for one of the apps is that the **sign up process should be done IN-APP**, meaning that the user should NOT be taken off the app to b2clocing.com page. Is that possible with AD B2C? So far our research indicates that is not possible. Unfortunatelly, this is a deal breaker for my customer so he is willing to move to Firebase which does offer that option.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up an identity provider for sign-up and sign-in in your Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) application, you **need** to specify a redirect URL, as this is the provider of trust.

You can not reference your own sites (or login.microsoftonline.com) in your applications and APIs for authenticating users with Azure AD B2C. You can use B2C in-App, but on some point in the authentication process, the microsoft authentication will take over. This is to make sure, that your app is not interfering with the users credentials. Which is the point of doing B2C.